Is it possible to calculate built in array functions using the Office.js API?
I'm trying to write an addin that takes a formula, parses it and then calculates the value of the formula. This all works for formulas that do not use ranges as we can use the Excel.Functions class to calculate built in Excel Functions.
However once I get to a formula like 5A1:A4, where A1:A4 is {1,2,3,4} we use the PRODUCT function from Excel.Functions to calculate it and it returns 12345 rather than {51,52,53,5*4}.
The same principle applies to almost any function that can take an array as an input in Excel. They either crash or produce unexpected behaviour.
Is there another class that supports array formulas instead? Do we know if it is being worked on in any way by Microsoft? It would be a bit annoying if we would have to implement all the functions ourselves.
